# Fiddler with iphone and ipad - local vhosts not working

Tags: iphone, ipad, fiddler, vhosts

I'm trying to run some local testing on iDevices but I must be missing something in the setup. I did that before when it all worked, so maybe someone can helpout:

I'm using Fiddler on a windows machine, have all devices set up via proxies and yes it also captures the traffic of the iphone and ipad.
I've got a few localhost vhosts set up, so running

http://mydomain.local

this works swimmingly on the windows phone via proxy to fiddler. but the iphone and ipad just says the server stopped responding.
The firewall is completely turned off and I can see all other traffic from the iDevices, so what could be the issue? Why does the iphone not read the hosts file but the windows phone does?

Comment: An iOS device is never going to "read the hosts file." Are you seeing the requests in question reach Fiddler? If not, then the iPhone probably has ".local" mapped such that it doesn't go to the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year late, but I had the same problem and can confirm that iOS does reserve ".local" to identify [Bonjour-accessible devices](http://support.apple.com/en-nz/TS3389)

If possible just change your domain extension to something else like ".lan" and your requests will go through the Fiddler proxy as expected.

Comment: Totally forgot about this thread already but: yes thats exactly what I ended up doing! Will mark this as resolved now in case someone else comes across this issue.